# Can I use a function argument to prove invertibility of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If all matrices can represent a linear transformation, can I refer to some general notion of the transformation associated with the matrix to make conclusions about the matrix?

For example, I want to prove a simple true/false statement,

> "If A and B are square matrices such that AB is invertible, then both A and B must be invertible."

I believe that the statement is true for the following reason:

> Assuming AB is well-defined and A and B are square, A and B have the same dimension. The product, AB is square as well then.
>
> AB is invertible and square, so the transformation AB represents is an
> isomorphism, thus the transformation associated with AB is a
> bijection.
>
> The transformation associated with AB is a bijection, so the
> transformation B represents is surjective and the transformation A
> represents is injective.
>
> Since both A and B have square matrices representing their linear
> transformations, injective and surjective respectively, the transformations must also
> be isomorphisms. Hence the transformation associated with A and B has
> an inverse, and thus A and B (the matrices) are invertible.

This feels convoluted and likely isn't the simplest solution. I am just wondering if it is OK to bring in the notion of the transformations the matrices could represent like this? Am I missing some subtlety?

Comment: This idea is good, and is what I would come up with rather than some row/column rank based argument. However you’re mixing up $A$ and $B$ with regards to injectivity/surjectivity (of the associated left-multiplication maps). At the end of the day it doesn’t matter since they turn out to both be bijective, but when writing the proof, you should be careful. One could also provide a fast argument using determinants, but I’d rather avoid it.

Comment: I think your argument is great; it shows a strong conceptual understanding of the material.

Comment: This is definitely the best way to prove this fact about matrices.

Comment: *"The transformation associated with AB is a bijection, so the transformation B represents is surjective and the transformation A represents is injective."*  .... I would flip these and say $AB$ has a trivial kernel and $\ker B\subseteq \ker (AB)$, so $B$ has a trivial kernel as well, i.e. $B$ is injective. (Optional: $A^T$ has a trivial kernel for same reason since $B^T A^T$ is an isomorphism, so $A$ is surjective).  These characterizations survive when $AB$ is invertible but $A$ and $B$ are not square per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrices and corresponding linear transformations have a *lot* of properties in common (I personally like to think of these as fundamentally properties of linear transformations, and that matrices inherit them and let us do calculations with them the moment we pick a coordinate system). Things like invertibility, determinant and rank, diagonalizablility, eigenvalues and their multiplicities, eigenvectors, commutativity (of square matrices and linear transformations with domain equal to codomain). I would even argue that if you have an inner product on your space, things like symmetry and orthogonality are also properties of linear transformations (although the corresponding matrices will only inherit these properties if your basis is orthonormal).

Some properties are necessarily intricately linked to a coordinate system, however. And thus only really properties that a matrix has and not a property of linear transformations. Being diagonal or triangular, for instance. A key feature here is that you care very much about the specific entries of the matrix. That's a telltale sign that you most likely have a pure matrix property and not a linear transformation property.

In your case, it is entirely fine to use the language of linear transformations to prove a statement that on the face of it says that it's about matrices, because everything in that problem translates without issue into statements about linear transformations.